# retrieve single image via its url in java

Tags: java, image, swing, image-processing, binary

I have a problem and I hope that you can help me. I would appreciate any help from anyone. The problem is the following.

I have a camera that has an http service, and I am communicating with the camera using the http. So the problem is that I send http request and I have back an http response in which I have a binary jpeg data. But I do not know how to convert that data into picture.

So my question is how can I convert that binary data into picture with java?

This is one example

http request:

```
GET (url to picture)
```

http response:

```
binary jpeg data
```

I thank to all of you in forward for all of your help.

```
URL url = new URL("http://10.10.1.154" + GETIMAGESCR());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
       // while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                // inputLine = in.readLine();
                 File file = new File("D:\\alphas\\proba.bin");
                 boolean postoi = file.createNewFile();
                 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("D:\\alphas\\proba.bin");
                 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                 out.write(in.readLine());
                // out.close();
               //  System.out.println("File created successfully.");
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            System.out.println("File created successfully.");
            out.close();
            in.close();
```

With this code I am getting the binary JPEG data, and I menage to save the data in a file. So the question is now how to convert this data into picture, or how to create the picture?
By the way I do not need to save the file that I get, if you have a way to create the picture directly it would be the best way

retrieve single image via its url in java

Comment: Can you use third party libraries?

Comment: You should be able to write the binary data directly to a .jpg file.

Comment: how to write to jpg directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to write byte data of image in response and set the proper content type, It will serve image from servlet

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me in more details how to do this, because I am new in this, so I don't quite know what to do here. Maybe you can send me a small example. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything. I am not getting a lot, but I'll try to fix it.Because I have a binary data from the camera, I just need to create the image. So I need to save the binary data that I receive from the camera like byte array and the to work with it?

Comment: yes I am there, I just don't know how to work with it so I get the image.:):):)

Comment: check the example from the posted link

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://site.com/image.jpeg");

    java.awt.Image image = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Please don't swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or are you just looking for this:

```
new ImageIcon(new URL("http://some.link.to/your/image.jpg"));
```

If you need to save the data from the URL, then just read the bytes from the corresponding InputStream and write the read bytes to a FileOutputStream: